# Specify complex password in Datamapper.setup

Tags: ruby, database, datamapper, padrino

I m trying to use Datamapper as ORM for my Ruby/Padrino application. To setup db connection, in databse.rb, I have:

```
when :development then DataMapper.setup(:default, "mysql://db_user:dsfsdfs@localhost/my_app_development")
```

This work fine. But my requirement is to have complex password, something like:

```
when :development then DataMapper.setup(:default, "mysql://db_user:Passw0rd#13@localhost/my_app_development")
```

This doesn't work and I get error:

```
ruby/1.9.1/gems/addressable-2.2.8/lib/addressable/uri.rb:1179:in `port=': Invalid port number: "Passw0rd" (Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError)
```

I figured out that the '#' character is problem. Then I attempted doing this:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, 
{
    :adapter => "mysql",
    :database => "my_app_development",
    :username => "db_user",
    :password => "Passw0rd#13",
    :host => "localhost"
})
```

When I do this, it seems like DM is ignoring the hash altogether; when I run

```
padrino rake db:create
```

It tries to connect as current logged in user, rather than the username specified here. Solution?

Comment: Not working, it says Invalid port number: "'Passw0rd"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you still need to have to declare it like following, in case you are not

```
when :development then
  DataMapper.setup(:default, 
  {
      :adapter => "mysql",
      :database => "my_app_development",
      :username => "db_user",
      :password => "Passw0rd#13",
      :host => "localhost"
  })
when :production then
  # rest of your code
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I am doing....I just replace the string with hash. Server is able to connect to DB with hash, its only the migration which isn't running. Seems like a bug in dm-migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Got it - the key `:username` should be `:user`. Basically, the hash should contains keys as understood by `Addressable::URI`